# User uploaded videos. How to view them?

Tags: html, flash, video, html5-video

I am making a kind of a social network. I am now in this part where I allow users to upload their videos and allow others to watch them. I have been researching on the HTML 5 video tag. People say that it would be better to give multiple sources for a video with three different formats namely ogg, mp4 and webm for different browser compability. But the user may upload any kind of video. It may be an avi or an flv or whatever. I am sure that there is a possible work-around. I know that facebook and youtube use flash. But I have exactly no idea on how to get started with flash on HTML. Is there any way around or any guide for flash ? Please Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that facebook and youtube use flash.

They do, but not as a work around for limited browser support for arbitrary uploaded videos.

They transcode the videos (you could do this with [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)) on a server into all the formats that they support.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an existing Flash video player, such as [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) or [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/).

Their integration is very easy, as you'll just have to include some JavaScript and CSS files in your HTML page header. Then for every video you want to display you're putting a small HTML snippet at the position where you want to show the player.

This is the default snippet for FlowPlayer:

```
<div class="flowplayer">
   <video>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="/path/to/intro.mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```